# How to limit an editor to edit and post in specific categories only?

Tags: wordpress, role

How to limit an editor to able to post or edit posts just in specific categories only?
any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with this plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/restrict-categories/

It is quite outdated but I use it in one of my project and works pretty good.

You can restrict by role or specific user as well.

Cheers,
Francesco

Comment: Thank You.  
"Advanced Access Manager" in "Plus Package" and "Restrict Taxonomies" and "Restrict User Access – WordPress Membership Plugin" also can do that.